# creating tabbedPane in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, tabs, jsf-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a tabbed pane component in JSF 2.0 (Sun Mojarra)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491969/how-do-i-get-a-tabbed-pane-component-in-jsf-2-0-sun-mojarra)

I'm making a project with JSF 2.0 and I'm using Apache Tomcat v.7.0.
I want to create tabs (most likely with tabbedPane), but I don't know how to do this.
Can anyone help me?